# Android dev: How to Increment ProgressBar in active activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, progress-bar

Suppose I'm watching a video in some video player.

I want to create a service which whenever an event of some kind occurs, the service increments the position of the progress bar in the currently active video player.

How can this be done?

Thanks!

Comment: "...some video player" - one you've written or just any 3rd party video player? If it's the latter then it isn't going to happen.

Comment: As I said, it isn't going to happen. It would be possible for somebody to create a video player app which allowed external components to send an Intent with a 'jump' (skip) action (together with a +/- offset) but this would be entirely proprietary and they'd need to publish the mechanism to do this.

Comment: Bad news for me.. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Sorry, but that's how Android works. On the one hand, any apps (and their components such as Activities, Services etc) CAN work with others regardless of whether they're written by the same person/company or whether they're 3rd party. On the other hand, there does have to be an 'agreement' (normally in the form of Intents and IntentFilters which are published and 'known' by all apps/components). Either that or there has to be a common API adopted by developers of all such app types and, at the end of the day, that's effectively what Intents in Android do anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need a player who offers that option with a ContentProvider, BroadcastReceiver or similar =(